# How to get string between the last nested `(` , and `)`?

Tags: php, regex

I have some MySQL statement like below:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS("=",DATE_FORMAT(ca.`date`,'%Y-%m-%d'),sa.`precence`)) as attendence
```

Above statement is a sample.

I want to get everything between the most deeply nested parentheses. In the above statement this is `ca.date,'%Y-%m-%d'`.

**Question**

How to do that with regex?

Comment: Find an SQL parser. If you don't mind, why are doing this? Parsing SQL after it has been created sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I have need this for an special usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex `/(\([^\(\)]+\))/`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aU6iV3/1)