# How to get string between the last nested `(` and `)`, but if no string is there, get string between direct parent `()` of that?

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I have this string:

```
date_format(from_days(datediff(now(),api.dob)),'%y')+0
```

I want to check content of the most nested `()`, that in above example is `now()`, but if no string is inside that, get the next one `api.dob`. And the same order for outer `()` if the content of the nested one is empty.
How can i do that with php ?
I have asked the same question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424963/how-to-get-string-between-the-last-nested-and)
But if the nested one content is empty, so should get next one in order.

Comment: @shA.t It matches both of them, if any thing inside `now()` existed, it also return `api.dob`, it should not do like that, in that case it should return only content of `now()`, but if `now()` is empty, so should return `api.dob`.

Comment: @shA.t but your last one not working with those strings that has only one `()`, and are not nested.

Comment: What about a conditional [like `\w+\((?<in>[^()]+)?\)(?(in)|,(?<res>[^()]+)\))`](https://regex101.com/r/GuWsQg/1)? If "res" is a success, take it. If not, grab the whole match value. Well, to get all the matches in Group 0, you may use a `\K` in the conditional - [`\w+\((?<in>[^()]+)?\)(?(in)|,\K(?<res>[^()]+))`](https://regex101.com/r/GuWsQg/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Thank you, it is working

Comment: @WiktoStribizew One another question. How we can check if the `res` group matched string is a word concatenated with `.` (dot) take it, if not get the content of parent `()`. Suppose this string : `if(awe.date_to >= date_sub(now(),interval 3 year),'yes','no')"`, the `res` group is `interval 3 year`, because this is not concatenated with `.` so get `awe.date_to`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a conditional regex like

```
\w+\((?<in>[^()]+)?\)(?(in)|,\K[^,()]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GuWsQg/4)

*Details*:

- `\w+` -  1 or more letters/digits/underscores
- `\(`  - a literal `(`
- `(?<in>[^()]+)?` - a named group "in" that captures 1 or more characters other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`
- `(?(in)` - a conditional checking if `in` group matched. If it did, match nothing
- `|` - else
- `,\K` - matches `,` and then omits the whole text matched so far
- `[^,()]+` - matches any 1+ characters other than `,`, `(` and `)`. (Not sure about the comma, please adjust as necessary)
- `)` - end of the conditional

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/M3TZY0):

```
$re = '/\w+\((?<in>[^()]+)?\)(?(in)|,\K[^,()]+)/';
$str = "date_format(from_days(datediff(now(),api.dob)),'%y')\ndate_format(from_days(datediff(now('here'),api.dob)),'%y')";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // => Array ( [0] => api.dob [1] => now('here') )
```

**Update**

Since the substring you need may come before the substring that actually sets a condition for the match selection, you need to actually capture all the parts that you are interested in and check which group matched.

I suggest the following variation:

```
(?:(?<res1>\w+(?:\.\w+)+)[^()]*\()?\b(?<res2>\w+\((?<in>[^()]+)?\))(?(in)|,(?<res3>\w+(?:\.\w+)+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GuWsQg/5)

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/DnPEEy):

```
$re = '/(?:(?<res1>\w+(?:\.\w+)+)[^()]*\()?\b(?<res2>\w+\((?<in>[^()]+)?\))(?(in)|,(?<res3>\w+(?:\.\w+)+))?/';
$strs = array('date_format(from_days(datediff(now(),api.dob)),\'%y\')',
'date_format(from_days(datediff(now(\'here\'),api.dob)),\'%y\')',
'if(awe.date_to >= date_sub(now(),interval 3 year),\'yes\',\'no\')"');

foreach ($strs as $str) {
    if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
        if (!empty($match["res3"])) {
            echo $match["res3"] . PHP_EOL;
        }
        else if (!empty($match["res1"])) {
            echo $match["res1"] . PHP_EOL;
        }
        else echo $match["res2"] . PHP_EOL;
    };
}
```

Comment: How we can check in else part the matched string that should be concatenated with `.`, if not then check parent `()` content and take dot concatenated string only once.

Comment: That `awe.date_to` comes before `now()`. You will need to capture that part as well as all others and then perform a deeper check of what your regex matched. See [`(?:(?<res1>\w+(?:\.\w+)+)[^()]*\()?\b(?<res2>\w+\((?<in>[^()]+)?\))(?(in)|,(?<res3>\w+(?:\.\w+)+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/GuWsQg/5).